# How does a class inherit the method from its parent class?

Tags: javascript

My question is about how a class (`Teacher`) inherits the method (`greeting`) from its parent class (`Person`).

```js
class Person { 

  constructor(name) { 
    this.name = name
  }

  greeting() { 
    console.log(`Hi! I'm ${this.name}`); 
  };

}

class Teacher extends Person { 
  constructor(first, subject) { 
    super(first); 

    this.subject = subject; 
  }
}

person = new Person;
teacher = new Teacher;
```

I'm using the above snippet as an example. I'm copying it into the console of a browser. I wasn't sure what to expect when I `console.dir(Person)` but I can see it looks like a `Function` object. Therefore it's not surprising that `Person.prototype.__proto__` points to `Object.prototype`, like a function would.

I also wasn't sure what to expect with `console.dir(Teacher)`. `Teacher.prototype.__proto__` also points to `Object.prototype`. It doesn't mention the `farewell` greeting of on `Person`, yet I know an instance of Teacher can use it. How does `Teacher`/an instance of `Teacher` have access to `Person.prototype`?

I know in typical prototypical inheritance, `Function.prototype` has a `__proto__` that points to `Object.prototype`.
I also believe classes are syntactical sugar over prototypical inheritance (which I think means same process but shortened syntax).

[Here's a useful photo of what I see when I see Teacher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gs7Rj.png)

Comment: Actually, `Teacher.prototype.__proto__ === Person.prototype;`

Comment: @hev Doh! Didn't see that - thank-you!

Answer (score 0):

ES6 Class syntax is a syntactical sugar for JavaScript. It's just functions and `[function].prototype` behind the scenes (and functions are objects too).

In JS we have prototypical inheritance, which means object we have objects **built upon** other objects - that'd be the `Function.prototype` object.

When you write a class method you are actually decorating the `[function].prototype` object

When you extend from a base class, your child class' prototype will be built upon the super class' (function) prototype object. Prototypical inheritance will allow you to access the super class' (object's) properties automatically.

In ES5.1 world there were some experiments with `Object.create` to build a "prototype (object) tree" to resolve the inheritance. This was useful for instance widget base behaviours (markup generation, formatting, etc.) and instance attributes (names, type names, instance specific attributes, etc.). If you really want to understand prototypical inheritance then I suggest you look that up as well. =)